# request_money failing in API: coinbase.wallet.error.InvalidRequestError: APIError(id=invalid_request): Missing parameter: `type`

Tags: coinbase-api

https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#request-money

Following example provided her I run into the issue:
coinbase.wallet.error.InvalidRequestError: APIError(id=invalid_request): Missing parameter: `type`

trekked into the code and saw that the param is added by the request_money function in client.py.

Seems to be an error in the API for the 2021-03-05 API.

I see it's a common issue (there's 2 other instances of this) but wondering if there was a recommended work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/api/#create-a-checkout

Use coinbase commerce. This is the supported API for trading amongst wallets.
Can confirm the checkout system works!

Wish that Coinbase advertised this a bit more :/